# Logging and Monitoring of Snowflake Enviroment

Tags: authentication, logging, user-controls, monitoring

I have a few questions about logging and monitoring I couldn't find an answer in the documentation to:

- Does the application keep logs of the creation, update and deletion of users and if yes, where and how may I find these logs?
- Does the application keep logs of changes to roles and assigned privileges?
- Does the application keep an audit-protocol of successful and unsuccessful logon-attempts?
- Where may the logs mentioned above be found and that is the retention-period?

Answer (score 0):

- Snowflake keeps track of the `CREATE` and `DROP`(delete) history of all `ACCOUNT`(top) level objects, including `USER`s.  Snowflake also keeps various activity logs like the `QUERY_HISTORY`, which can be analyzed for `ALTER`(update) of objects, but it is complicated to use.  Most logs are kept in the `SNOWFLAKE` database and the ones most relevant to your question are views in the `ACCOUNT_USAGE` schema.
- Snowflake keeps a record of `GRANT` and `REVOKE` in the two `ACCOUNT_USAGE` schema views `GRANTS_TO_ROLES` and `GRANTS_TO_USERS`.  The problem primo 2023 is that the info is presented with a 30 minutes delay in my experience.  There is an instant `SHOW GRANTS` command but it does not show history and is specific to a single object at a time. Each database has an `INFORMATION_SCHEMA` with `%_PERMISSIONS` views for `OBJECT`, `TABLE` and `USAGE`, but these have hard to understand access filters on them (the `SNOWFLAKE` database mentioned above now has a couple of easy to understand access roles, and the `ACCOUNTADMIN` role will see everything)
- Yes, a view called `SNOWFLAKE.ACCOUNT_USAGE.LOGIN_HISTORY`, presented with a delay.  There is also a table function `SNOWFLAKE.INFORMATION_SCHEMA.LOGIN_HISTORY()` with instant info, but with hard to understand filtering.  Keep in mind that even the most privileged role `ACCOUNTADMIN` will not see everything with these filters :O
- As I've mentioned above the main log source is the `SNOWFLAKE` database and the views in the `ACCOUNT_USAGE` schema.  Database object permissions are kept in the `INFORMATION_SCHEMA` of each database.  The retention time of the activity view events in `ACCOUNT_USAGE` schema is 365 days per primo 2023.  "Instant" activity logs in the `SNOWFLAKE.INFORMATION_SCHEMA` vary, mostly 1-3 weeks.